# It says my import has an error, but I don't know why

Tags: java

```
import java.lang.Math.*;
```

/***tester**.java:3: error: illegal start of type
import java.lang.Math.*;
^
**tester**.java:3: error:  expected
import java.lang.Math>*;
^

```
public class Circle
{
    public static double computeArea(double radius)
    {
        return (Math.PI) * (radius * radius);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(computeArea(2.0));
        System.out.println(computeArea(5.3));
}
}
```

Comment: You should import the class without the dot and the star after it.

Answer (score 1):

The Math class is a class in Java and it is not a package. So your code should be like this:

```
class Main
{
    public static double computeArea(double radius)
    {
        return (Math.PI) * (radius * radius);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(computeArea(2.0));
        System.out.println(computeArea(5.3));
    }
}
```

However, you could import it only with the static keyword next to the import like this (the asterisk meaning import all of the code):

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
```

So you won't get that error again.

Answer (score 0):

With non-static imports, you can only import all the things in a package. `java.lang.Math` is a class, not a package, so this doesn't work.

However, you can statically import all static symbols (methods and fields) in a class:

```
import static  java.lang.Math.*;
```